# Hooking Django App to subdirectory using mod_wsgi and apache on Centos 5

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

### Background:

I am working on bringing a Django App into production for my office. So far the app has been developed and works and all that needs to be done is to deploy said app. A task that is unfortunately more cumbersome than developing the app itself. I am working on a Centos 5.11 server with Apache 2.2, mod_wsgi 3.3 and both Python 2.7 and Django 1.9 in virtualenv.

### The problem

The issue I am running into is hooking the Django App to my domain's subdirectory (www.abc.example.com/FR/) but I am running into problems when configuring apache's httpd.conf where my added settings do not seem to be saved. I have run the following commands as per the httpd.conf's comments on making sure changes are saved upon restart:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/apache_conf_distiller --update 
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/build_apache_conf
```

The guides that I have used have lead me to the following code:
* note that '~' is representative of /home/[username]

**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule wsgi_module extramodules/mod_wsgi.so
```

...

```
WSGIScriptAlias /FR ~/public_html/FR/django.wsgi
WSGIPythonPath ~/public_html/FR

<Directory ~/mydjango/IFTP>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

**django.wsgi** at ~/public_html/FR/django.wsgi

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('~/mydjango')
sys.path.append('~/mydjango/IFTP')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'IFTP.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**wsgi.py** at ~/mydjango/IFTP/wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "IFTP.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### Edit 1:

My apologies, I should have further specified that the problem is that these settings are not taking effect. When I go to www.abc.example.com/FR/ I encounter a 404 not found so the wsgi script is either misconfigured or not setup properly, which is where I need assistance.

Comment: There's no point in having both django.wsgi and wsgi.py. You've made Apache point at django.wsgi; the other file is therefore not used.

Comment: But you haven't really said what is going wrong. What does "my added settings do not seem to be saved" mean?

Comment: A separate WSGI script file is still useful where you need to set up directories in ``sys.path`` or environment variables which are specific to the deployment type and which when added to ``wsgi.py`` would interfere with running of the application under a separate environment.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, my apologies, the problem is that having done all of this, I am still encountering a 404 when going to www.abc.example.com/FR/. Apache has been restarted with these settings saved but I cannot tell whether it is that the settings above are incorrect or there is some server-side error causing the 404.

Comment: To determine whether the 404 is coming from Django, temporarily set ``DEBUG=True`` in the Django settings module. That will generate a very pretty response in browser if is Django and your ``urls.py`` is not setup correctly for how request is being passed. Your ``urls.py`` should not have ``FR`` leading URL patterns with above Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I discovered that the issues were in the django.wsgi file that provided an unnecessary extra layer. I changed my httpd.conf file to the code below, further specifying the path for my virtualenv and linking to the wsgi.py file.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module extramodules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /FR ~/mydjango/IFTP/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath "~/mydjango/lib/python2.7/site-packages:~/mydjango"
WSGIPythonHome ~/mydjango

<Directory ~/mydjango/IFTP>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Now you have it working, use daemon mode instead and also setup the virtual environment in better way. See http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/using-python-virtual-environments-with.html